# How to create a modal in moodle using mustache Template

Tags: javascript, php, moodle, mustache, simplemodal

How can i  create a modal in moodle using mustache Template, the js must be in a separate file, i don't know hot to put this together, the documentation it's a little bit hard
I am doing this inside a local plugin.
I'm following the documentation, i have this file structure

```
├── amd
│   ├── build
│   │   └── modal.min.js
│   └── src
│       └── modal.js
├── classes
│   └── form
│       └── edit.php
├── index.php
├── manage.php
├── styles.css
├── templates
│   └── index.mustache
└── version.php
```

inside the index.php i call the js using this

```
$PAGE->requires->js_call_amd('amd/src/modal', 'init');
```

And in the modal.js i only have a console log, and it doesn't print i always get this error

```
define([], function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
      console.log('Hello world');
    },
  };
});
```

Error :

```
ncaught Error: Script error for "amd/srcmodal"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Comment: Include your code

Comment: Done, i have only include the moodle example but doesn't work, so i haven't do anything